# Laravel: failing to send email?

Tags: php, laravel, php-5.5

Error

Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=***********@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Using Laravel 5.5 and on localhost, can anyone help?

Comment: I'm using Laravel, I don't know what you mean?

Comment: My credentials are working fine as I tried logging in manually, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line
`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`

To this
`MAIL_DRIVER=mail`